# Image gallery slider quasar

Tags: javascript, quasar

I am new in quasar framework.  
I need to know how to make image gallery slider automatic change  in a few second. how i can setting it? 
sorry if my grammar bad.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your code attempts for future questions.

See the quasar documentation here: http://quasar-framework.org/components/slider.html

A simply example about you want:

```
<p class="caption">
    Slider with Infinite Scroll and Autoplay
  </p>
  <q-slider infinite autoplay arrows dots class="text-white">
    <div slot="slide" class="bg-primary centered">
      Slide 1
    </div>
    <div slot="slide" class="bg-secondary centered">
      Slide 2
    </div>
    <div slot="slide" class="bg-tertiary centered">
      Slide 3
    </div>
  </q-slider>
```

'autoplay' property can be boolean or number(represents the number of milliseconds between scrolls.)